# Maximally dense Unit Distance Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, tiling

At [Unit distance graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph): Paul Erdős (1946) posed the problem of estimating how many pairs of points in a set of n points could be at unit distance from each other. In graph theoretic terms, how dense can a unit distance graph be?

$e =  \left \lfloor{v^{4/3}}\right \rfloor  $ is the Spencer-Szemerédi-Trotter upper bound. The Hamming 3,3 graph, with 27 vertices and 81 unit edges, meets this bound.  I just noticed that this graph is non-rigid, so here's another embedding:

[image: Hamming 3,3]

Playing around with the infinite embeddings, I found this convergence. With 21 vertices and 57 edges, it also meets the upper bound.

[image: maximal 21]

Are there other unit distance graphs that match the upper bound?  According to [A186705](https://oeis.org/A186705), there are maximal graphs for 9, 12, 13, and 14 vertices (18, 27, 30, 33 edges).

EDIT:  Here's 16 vertices with 41 edges. From this, (13,14,15,16)->(30,33,37,41) can easily be derived. Notice that vertex set (1,2,11,15,12,16,6) makes a [Moser spindle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoserSpindle.html).

[image: Maximum Unit-distance graph on 16 vertices]

Also note that $16^{4/3}=40.3175$, so this exceeds the Spencer-Szemerédi-Trotter upper bound. I was just reading last night that the bound had been proven in 6 different ways. Did I break it?

Answer (score 7):

You might be misunderstanding the upper bound. It's more like the upper bound is $O(n^{4/3})$. The actual upper bound is $cn^{4/3}$ where $c = 8$. The paper establishing the upper bound can be found [here](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~trotter/papers/44.pdf). Thank you @domotorp for your comment which provided [this paper](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~hsmith90/4022/Unit_Distances.pdf) which sets constant $c = 8$.

Comment: Actually, an upper bound is $8n^{4/3}$, see https://people.math.gatech.edu/~hsmith90/4022/Unit_Distances.pdf